# How to design a quantitative research topic based on effects of learning aids on learning mathematics at university

Tags: statistics

Am trying to design a quantitative research topic and question based on the effects of using teaching and learning aids on teaching and learning of mathematics at university level.
The topic must have a dependent and independent variable.
Making it researchable within the campus is my main aim.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your local Department may have a committee that deals with cognate matters. It is best to try to find a receptive faculty member.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependent variable could be grade awarded on student research  projects, and your independent variable could be whether or not the student solicited help from Math.SE.

Comment: in that angular approach, how do I phrase the topic

Comment: "Does Math.SE help students achieve higher grades?"